# AnyLogic stopped running and won't reopen. I get a popup window saying "An error has occurred. See the log file". Suggestions?

Tags: anylogic

I was running a model then canceled it before it was completed. Not anything out of the ordinary. Then, my machine stopped working (black screen with no mouse responsiveness, it was weird) and after a restart via task manager, I can't reopen AnyLogic. I'm using v8.3 with a University researcher license. I've opened the log file per the pop-up error message below but I don't know what I'm looking for. It's >10,000 lines with messages that say "Application Error" or "Can't Instantiate" or something along those lines. Any suggestions on what to do? Thanks.

[Pop-up error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kddcf.png)

Comment: Rename the (hidden) `.AnyLogicUniversity` (I think for the Uni Researcher edition) folder in your user directory and start AnyLogic. That will reset AnyLogic to its 'original' state (including resetting all preferences, etc.) and sometimes gets 'corrupted' by model errors. (You may have to re-apply your license details though.) By renaming it you can revert back if needed.

Comment: OK added it as an answer for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the (hidden) `.AnyLogicUniversity` (I think for the Uni Researcher edition) folder in your user directory and start AnyLogic. That will reset AnyLogic to its as-installed state (including resetting all preferences, etc.) and sometimes gets 'corrupted' by model errors. (You may have to re-apply your license details though.)

By renaming the folder you can revert back if needed.